# What does "all"mean in "All we know about other people's minds we know from what they do."?

Tags: relative-clauses

Does "all" mean "all of us":

> **All of us** know about other people's minds we know from what they do.

or "all the things that"?

> We know all the things that we know about other people's minds from what they do.

Comment: Your second guess is correct. We can only truly know people by their actions.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the word all as a preposition after the subject pronoun we (we all) or the phrase 'all of' before the object pronoun us (all of us), it implies every one of us.

When you use it as a preposition in front of we (all we), it means everything or the only thing. So the sentence means "Everything that we know about.........".